# Sorting multidimensional array by specific field

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to sort a multi-dimensionsal array that looks like the following:

```
 var test_array = { "214": { "id": "214", "name": "Mike Smith", "salary": 50000 }, 
"336": { "id": "336", "name": "John Doe", "salary": 60000 }, 
"134": { "id": "134", "name": "Jane Doe", "salary": 100000 }, 
"914": { "id": "914", "name": "Bob White", "salary": 25000 } };
```

I'd like to sort descending by the salary field and jQuery functions are acceptable in the solution.

Comment: Thank you for posting your requirements. Now please post your attempt...

Comment: A side note: it's not an array

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sorting-objects-in-an-array-by-a-field-value-in-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You can't sort your *array*, because in fact it's an object instead of an array.

And JS objects are **unordered** collections of name/value pairs.

If you want order, use arrays instead of objects, e.g.

```
var test_array = [
    { "id": "214", "name": "Mike Smith", "salary": 50000 }, 
    { "id": "336", "name": "John Doe", "salary": 60000 }, 
    { "id": "134", "name": "Jane Doe", "salary": 100000 }, 
    { "id": "914", "name": "Bob White", "salary": 25000 }
];
test_array.sort(function(a,b){
    if(a.salary < b.salary) return -1;
    if(a.salary > b.salary) return 1;
    return 0;
});
```

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: OP doesn't have an array. +1

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: I don't have any doubts. Which makes this question just *incomplete*, **NOT** *incorrect*.

Comment: @zerkms It's not incomplete. OP got the terminology wrong. It's perfectly clear what he wants to accomplish. He wants his id/name/salary objects based on the salary. Which btw Oriol just edited into this answer. I've removed my downvote.